# ArcGIS - FME coordinate rounding difference

Tags: arcgis, esri

I've got a weird difference between x-y coordinates between two points which is causing some issues.
Using a FGDB, with a featureclass with points included, as a basemap I draw a polygon using the esri snapping function on. This polygon has its corners snapped to the points and is saved in a .shp shape file. In ArcMap the x-y coordinates of the corner points are exactly the same as the points underneath them.

Now when using FME and FME dataviewer these points have slightly different x-y coordinates only differing on the 9th decimal. Meaning that the points do not fall inside the polygon creating difficulties.

To keep it simple the x-coordinate of the point is:
67479.59299999848
and the x-coordinate of the polygon corner point is:
67479.593000002205

Now my question is this: 
What makes the differences because the difference isn't just plain and simple rounding. With rounding I would expect a .593000000000 not a 2205 at the end.

I have screenshots but I cannot post pictures with <10 reputation...

Hope someone has an answer to how this works!

Cheers,

Comment: I would refer to http://gis.stackexchange.com/ for GIS related questions.

Comment: Oh sorry didn't know that existed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok let me answer my own question (which I also put on an FME forum). All credit for this answer goes to David R. from FME community knowledge center.

> David R.
>   Hi
>
> there are a few other threads in here that touch on the same issue,
>   but the short answer is that this is due to internal rounding "errors"
>   when converting fractions between base 10 (you and me) and base 2 (the
>   computer). It should not make any difference for most applications.
>
> You can find a more detailed answer here:
>   http://floating-point-gui.de/basic/
>
> David